# Filtering based on class constants with laravel filter

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am trying to filter a collection of data based on a constants defined in a class. The `$results` is a Laravel Collection. When I attempt to filter, I receive this:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method MatchRecord::constant()

What am I doing wrong or what other way can I filter results based the constants defined in the `MatchRecord` Class?

```
class MatchRecord
{
   /**
    * Match List
    * @var Collection
    */
    private $results;

    const ERROR = 0;
    const ARENA = 1;
    const CAMPAIGN = 2;
    const CUSTOM = 3;
    const WARZONE = 4;

   /**
    * Get list of matches from results for given mode
    * @param  String $matchType
    * @return Collection
    */
    public function getMatchesByType($matchType)
    {
        // results[Id][GameMode]
        $filteredMatches = $this->results->filter(function ($match) use ($matchType) {
                return $match['Id']['GameMode'] === self::constant(strtoupper($matchType));
        });

        return $filteredMatches;
    }
}
```

https://gyazo.com/b72ae052d795a1009a2c97141d629ec0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The next thing I tried after I posted work. FML. Should have just have just given it an extra five minutes of trying.

```
$filteredMatches = $this->results->filter(function ($match) use ($matchType) {
    return $match['Id']['GameMode'] === constant('Self::'.strtoupper($matchType));
});
```

The way I was calling constant() was not correct.

Comment: Missing a `)` at the end of return line

Comment: Mistake in copy paste from editor on my self answer, but I did get it working.